# ASP.NET MVC 4 Bundles not always loaded

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, bundle

In my ASP.NET MVC 4 application I have jquery-ui and other scripts in a Bundle. And I also have some specific javascript code in the corresponding page. In one of those pages I need to use "sortable()", a function that depends on jQuery UI.

**Problem:**

The first time I load the page everything is fine but, if I do a reload with cache override (CTRL+F5) the Bundle with the scripts is not being loaded correctly and I have an error that "sortable()" is not a function.

I'm rendering the Bundle at the end of the page, right before the closing body tag, and I'm rendering the script section right after the Bundle render.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Also, I'm not bundling the minified version of jQuery UI.

Firefox gives me this error:

> XMLHttpRequest synchronous in main thread is obsolete...

I've been searching and changing but I can't find where the problem may be.

**EDIT:**

I've been testing and I noticed that this only happens when I apply functions of jQuery UI to elements inside partial views.

Also I have inserted in the  of the main page:

```
<script src='~/Content/scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js'></script>
```

And jQuery-UI stills undefined...

Comment: This doesn't sound like a bundling problem to me, but a problem with your partial views. Can you post some of the relevant JS from your partials? Also, are you including scripts directly in your partials, or referencing HTML in a partial from one of the scripts loaded from your main page / layout.cshtml?

Comment: Now that you say it, I've checked better and tried to put @{ Layout = null } in my partial views and I noticed that now jquery-ui is NOT being loaded twice... I don't know if that really solved the problem, but it looks like that the partial views were overriding my first jquery load. Seems possible?

Comment: It could definitely be possible if the scripts were being bundled with your main page and your partial view

Comment: Well, for now the problem seems solved. Thanks for the tip.